# Crystal reports custom chart

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I want to implement a graph in crystal report that looks like a progress bar (a gradient image) and a circle containing marks should be placed according to percentage. As shown in [this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fc2zG.jpg). Any one please help how i can achieve this

Comment: beautiful pic! Interesting doing this with crystal

Answer (score 2):

Crystal Reports doesn't have native support for this type of graph.

Here's an approximation:

- create bar image and circular image (omit score)
- create a new report (it will be a sub-report)
- position two images in the Details section; align with each other
- add three numeric parameters: Low, High, Score
- add Low parameter to left edge of bar image; add High parameter to right edge
- add Score parameter and position above circular image; size to match image's width
- create a formula named 'Position' (see text below)
- right click circular image and select Size and Position...; add the Position formula to the X-position's conditional formula
- do the same thing for the Score parameter's X-position conditional formula
- suppress all sections but Details
- embed sub-report in other reports as desired

Formula text:

```
//{@Position}
//
// RETURNS: position in inches
// TODO: set properties to match your layout
//
// width of circle image (inches)
Local Numbervar circleDiameter:= 0.5;

// X position of left edge of image (inches)
Local Numbervar barLeftX:=1;

// X position of right edge of image (inches)
Local Numbervar barRightX:=3;

// width of bar image
Local Numbervar barWidth:= barRightX - barLeftX;

// relative position of score in relation to low and high scores
Local Numbervar relativePosition:={?Score} / ({?High} - {?Low});

// calculate position of image's X position (return value in INCHES)
barLeftX + (barWidth * relativePosition) - (circleDiameter/2)
```

Conditional Formula text:

```
// 
// convert inches to twips (1440 twips/inch); confusing because UI uses inches
//
{@Position}*1440
```

<strike>For some reason, Crystal Reports 2008 is ignoring the conditional formula.  I'll do some research and post findings.</strike>

Otherwise, consider a Chart replacement:

- [CRChart](http://www.threedgraphics.com/tdg/products/tools/crchart/product_info.php)